# Clicking on GLTF models - Threejs

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm working on a threejs project where I'm trying to load a GLTF file containing geometric shapes. I am writing a logic to get info, for now just the name, of the shapes that I click within the GLTF file. For now, I am just using console.log() to print the name of the shape I have clicked. I also want a side navigation bar to appear with the name of the component, I have a simple OpenNav() function for the navigation bar, as shown below. I now want to use the HTML header tag to display **found[index].object.name** (the component's name). I am kind of stuck here. How do I achieve this?

```
<div id = "mySidenav" class = "sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <h2>Hello world!</h2>
</div>
    <script src = "three.js"></script>
    <script type = "module" src = "index.js"></script>
    <script>
        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        }  
    </script>
```

**click event function in index.js**

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
}

window.addEventListener('click', event => {  
  // enables object selection
  clickMouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  clickMouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  // enables different object selection 
  raycaster.setFromCamera( clickMouse, camera );
  //checking mesh objects the ray are intersecting with
  const found = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
  // console.log(found);
  // console.log(found[0]);
  if(found.length > 0){
      // console.log(found);
       for (let index = 0; index < found.length; index++) {
         if (found[index].object.name === "Cone") {
            console.log(found[index].object.name);          
            openNav();
         }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have it.

#### I would recommend you replace:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', event => {  
  // enables object selection
  clickMouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  clickMouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  // enables different object selection 
  raycaster.setFromCamera( clickMouse, camera );
  //checking mesh objects the ray are intersecting with
  const found = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
  // console.log(found);
  // console.log(found[0]);
  if(found.length > 0){
      // console.log(found);
       for (let index = 0; index < found.length; index++) {
         if (found[index].object.name === "Cone") {
            console.log(found[index].object.name);          
            openNav();
         }
    }
  }
})
```

#### With this:

```js
function Listener(listener, mesh, callback) {
    let objects = [mesh];
    let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    let mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener(listener, raycast, false);
    function raycast(e) {
        mouse.x = (e.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(e.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);
        let intersect = intersects[0];
        if (typeof intersect !== "undefined") {
            callback(e, intersect);
        }
    }
}
for (let i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i++) {
    Listener('click', scene.children[i], (e, intersect) => {
        let object = intersect.object;
        if (object.name === 'Cone') {
            openNav();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I did not try your method. I used `shape = found[index].object.name ` and `document.getElementById("external").innerHTML = "Shape : " + shape;` to display the component name